# How to extend the table when text longer then the size of a cell is inserted?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: image of table]

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \begin{document}

    \tikzset{ 
        table/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw=black,
                align=center
            },
            minimum height=1.5em,
            text depth=0.5ex,
            text height=2ex,
            nodes in empty cells,
    %%
            every even row/.style={
                nodes={fill=gray!20}
            },
            column 1/.style={
                nodes={text width=2em,font=\bfseries}
            },
            row 1/.style={
                nodes={
                    fill=black,
                    text=white,
                    font=\bfseries
                }
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix (first) [table,text width=6em]
    {
    & Monday   & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday\\
    1   & A & B & C & D & E \\
    2   & F & G & H & J & K \\
    3   & A & B & C & D & E \\
    4   & F & G & H & J & K \\
    };


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

What if I write to the first cell 'Monday is the first day of the day' instead of just monday?

I want the cell to adapt vertically, increasing the height of the whole row, to accomodate the text

How to do that?

Comment: You mean the linebreaks are added or the cell **width** is increased?

Comment: the extra text that would exceed the cell width simply doesnt show up...I want the extra text to automatically go to a new newline.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a not-so-manual approach by just deciding on how many lines the largest test will cover in the first row and adjusting the row height accordingly

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}

    \tikzset{ 
        table/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw=black,
                minimum width=6em,
            },
            every even row/.style={
                nodes={fill=gray!20}
            },
            row 1/.style={
                nodes={draw,
                    fill=black,
                    text=white,
                    font=\bfseries,
                    align=center,
                    anchor=center,
                    minimum height=9ex, % Roughly 3ex for each line break
                    inner sep=0,
                },
            },
            column 1/.style={
                nodes={minimum width=2em,font=\bfseries},
            },
            row 1 column 6/.style={text width=4em,align=center,} % Align the width of the cell
        }
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (first) [table]
    {
    & Monday   & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday I'm in love\\
    1   & A & B & C & D & E \\
    2   & F & G & H & J & K \\
    3   & A & B & C & D & E \\ 
    4   & F & G & H & J & K \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, The Cure is playing on the radio.